# How to find out which versions of JARs were used in the eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have inherited an eclipse project which has a couple of dependencies.   There is no documentation and the maintainer is no longer available.
Some of them were referenced in the project setup and I could just download the correct jars and add them. There are no further references in the build path.
But now I see that there are still imports in the source code which are unresolved, like

```
import org.apache.cxf.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

Here is the .project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Server</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

and .classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc4.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core.CXF_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Server/src/libs/fontbox-1.8.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Server/src/libs/pdfbox-1.8.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Server/src/libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Server/src/libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Regarding the Application Server, I checked with test environment, there is nothing special configured for Tomcat.

My questions are :

1. how can it be that these are not visible as incorrect libary dependencies in the build path?
2. especially when it comes to cxf, is there a way to find out which version was used?

Comment: Is this installed somewhere in production or test? do you know if it was supposed to work with a specific application server, cause the javax part could come from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javax.servlet is versione 2.5 in Tomcat 6 from your configuration:

```
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0"/>.
```

and your application should simply depend on the jars included in Tomcat.

For the CXF I think you should first add a CXF runtime to your Eclipse under: Preferences > WebServices > CXF.2 Preferences > CXF Runtime. The specific version cannot be deducted from what you reported. You can look here: https://cxf.apache.org/download.html

You should consider upgrading Java, Tomcat and CXF to newer versions, since Tomcat 6 is old and in end of life since 2017.

Note: when you build your project the required CXF jars should end up in /WEB-INF/lib in you war. If you run in a Server in Eclipse they will be placed in a temproary folder, something like:

```
[WORKSPACE]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebServiceProject\WEB-INF\lib\
```

Comment: thank you, this already helps a lot. With CFX, I guess I can only test and hope it works. Can you elaborate your note please? Does this mean there is a difference between running in Eclipse and deployed state there I need to take into account?

Comment: I mean that when you build a project maven usually puts the all the jar files your app depends from inside the war under /WEB-INF/lib, such that when you deploy the war in tomcat on the server the files are found (not including the jar already found in tomcat like the servlet file). The wars are extracted by tomcat in a working dir in its path. When you test a webapp by executing it embedded in eclipse, the embedded tomcat has a folder where it keeps all the files for each web app you test at the path given above. First you have to create a Server for running tomcat apps from settings